# Is it possible to limit the device/camera movement in Facebook AR Studio?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

For example there is an image using canvas with a rectangle in World Space. In doing so the camera/device can look around freely with the image placed into the "real" world. I wonder if there is a way to limit that "movement", spanning left to right, top to bottom but the device/camera view is limited  at a certain point. Even if users turn the device/camera 360degrees, the view is stuck at a certain point. Say if the user pans left the camera/device stops at rotationY: 9, If right then stops at rotationY :-15, rotationX is stuck at 0.

I saw there's a BoundBox in the documentation but not sure what that is. There's a DeviceMotionModule but no idea how to use it. I don't know what the script example given is suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `DeviceMotion`. https://sparkar.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/devicemotionmodule

The script example rotates the 3d plane according to the rotation of the phone. 
You will have to do some maths to position your objects according to rules and signal you get from DeviceMotion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reactive module you can access the "Clamp" method which is actually made to restrict values between two bounds. I recently found this out because I had a similar problem.  [From this page](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/reactivemodule)

clamp(x: ScalarSignal, min: ScalarSignal, max: ScalarSignal): ScalarSignal

Returns a signal with the value that is the value of the given x signal constrained to lie between the values of the given min and max signals.

Note: The behavior is undefined if min is greater than max.